# Google Analytic tracking code

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-analytics-api

I tried to track event of an application that run on localhost with Google analytic... but Google Analytic only track event from fixed URL... I just want to know is there any way to create an account on Google Analytic that track global event that sent to my account??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can track without fixed URL

Just give your domain name as local.local for example

- choose the option Multiple top-level domains when u set your account
- and set domain name as none      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);

that is all